# Information stored on Heroku Application lost after server goes idle and starts up again?

Tags: python, heroku, server

I am saving some information to a textfile that is stored in my Heroku app. It can be updated by post requests from a user using an IOS device. It all works and it stores the information. But as you all know the Heroku app goes idle after an hour. So after the server goes idle and i make a GET request, the information previously put is lost?

There is a link in my heroku apps like afternoon-springs.... /ResetAllInfo but that link is never accessed. I watched the heroku logs to see.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like Heroku does not support write to filesystem: [Heroku Documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) and [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

So it's just not possible. Heroku suggests:

> Use the provided PostgreSQL database instead of a filesystem database

Comment: Im guessing it costs to use it?

Comment: @hamzah Usage is free to a limit, see their [pricing page](https://www.heroku.com/pricing)